# Dynamic Load Class from within an unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, unmanaged, dynamic-loading, c#-native-library

I am trying to dynamically load classes from within an unmanaged (COM) DLL. I am not sure the language it was written in, it is 3rd party that does not exist anymore.
I am able to use NativeLibrary.Load on the path to the DLL without issue, but I am now not sure how to get an instance of a class within the DLL.

I am able to register the DLL on my dev machine, so I know how to utilize it, but I am not going to be able to register it on the target machine. So I am having to dynamically load it in the actual application.

I am also aware of GetProcAddress, but this is for the procedure within the class, which I am not able to get an instance of.

For instance, lets call it MyCustom.dll, which contains a class named MyClass, which then contains a procedure named Run(). I can load MyCustom.dll without issue and get a ptr for it, but I am not able to get access to the Run() procedure that I need to call using GetProcAddress.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-dllgetclassobject

Comment: Thank you Hans-Passant, I will look into using DLLGetClassObject.  I found this other stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223629/how-do-i-write-dllgetclassobject-as-a-c-sharp-delegate) on how to use this in C# as I need, so hopefully it will be the solution I am needing. Thank you very much.